# bind-address how does it work in mysql

Tags: mysql, configuration

I have a mysql running with bind-address "10.4.0.211".

From the documentation, I understand it like, the server accepts connections only from the IP - 10.4.0.211.

But I could able to connect to this mysql from another new server with the below configurations.

```
eth0      inet addr:10.8.0.7  
eth1      inet addr:10.11.0.50  
lo        inet addr:127.0.0.1
```

None of the above  has the bind address in them, but how come I am able to connect to the service. Please clarify.

I am suing the below connections string from the new server.

```
mysql -u<<username>> -p<<password>>  -h<<hostname of the mysql running server>> -A
```

Answer (score 1):

> From the documentation, I understand it like, the server accepts connections only from the IP - 10.4.0.211.

Your understanding is incorrect.

It has nothing to do with where the connection is *coming from*.

The server listens and accepts connections only **on** (not "from") the stated address.  Where you can connect **from** is determined by the entries in the `mysql`.`user` table, which are created by `GRANT` statements, and, of course, whether you have network connectivity to the address where MySQL is listening.

Answer (score 0):

[Bind Address](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) it's mentioned like 
If you intend to bind the server to a specific address, be sure that the mysql.user grant table contains an account with administrative privileges that you can use connect to that address. Otherwise, you will not be able to shut down the server. For example, if you bind to 0.0.0.0, you can connect to the server using all existing accounts. But if you bind to 127.0.0.1, the server accepts connections only on that address. In this case, first make sure that the 'root'@'127.0.0.1' account is present in the mysql.user table so that you can still connect to the server to shut it down.

So, make sure that you have a account exists with **'mysql_user'@'10.4.0.211'** and then try to connect from other IP than **10.4.0.211**
Otherwise, you can report this issue to http://bugs.mysql.com/ mention specific MySQL version and OS details where your server is running

Comment: Your answer works for those who face connections denies alerts due to bind address but mine is different case. watch my question again. thanks.